# Javascript / Jquery Checkbox Image

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a list of checkboxes as images from DHTMLX.

**Unchecked**

```
<td valign="middle" align="center" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="" title="">
   <img onclick="new eXcell_ch(this.parentNode).changeState(true); (arguments[0]||event).cancelBubble=true; " src="/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/imgs/item_chk0.gif" title="">
</td>
```

**Checked**

```
<td valign="middle" align="center" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="" title="">
  <img onclick="new eXcell_ch(this.parentNode).changeState(true); (arguments[0]||event).cancelBubble=true; " src="/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/imgs/item_chk1.gif" title="">
</td>
```

**Button (Batch Tagging)**

```
<input type="submit" onclick="DoRowBatch()" style="width:150px; background-color:darkslateblue;" class="formsubfree" value="Tag Selected Applications" id="ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.5." name="ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.5.">
```

Clicking on the checkbox they can go to the next step (batch tag), if they don't then an alert needs to pop up saying "Select at least one checkbox"

```
function DoRowBatch() {
   var Checkedlist = mygrid.getCheckedRows(15);
   if (CheckedList.checked){
      document.getElementById('ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.4.').value = Checkedlist;
      document.getElementById('ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.5.').click();
   }
   else
   { 
     alert ("You must first select applications, using the checkboxes, before bulk tagging them"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: An alert should show if the checkbox is not clicked. If not it should go ahead with group tagging...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<img onclick="new eXcell_ch(this.parentNode).changeState(true); (arguments[0]||event).cancelBubble=true; " src="/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/imgs/item_chk0.gif" title="">

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () 
{
    if($("img[src='/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/imgs/item_chk0.gif']").length > 0)
    {
        //show Popup
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: @ Thaigo..Thank you. But managed to work something along your code.

if (Checkedlist.length !== 0 )

Comment: Yeap, I point just the idea. I hope it was helpful for you. Cheers